# scalatest Flatespec test result of println

Tags: scalatest

I am using scalatest FlatSpec Library in order to test my code. 
Below is the function I wrote in order to test my code:

```
def compareToHello (a:String) = {
 a match {case "Hello" => println ("Hello")
case _ => println("error")}
}
```

For the test part :

```
import org.scalatest.{ FlatSpec, GivenWhenThen, Matchers } 
class AestA extends FlatSpec with GivenWhenThen with Matchers {
"Implemented function" should "compare input string to hello"in {
val test=compareToHello("Hello)
assert 
}

}
```

I am facing a problem regarding what to put in the assert as the output of my function is displayed in console. 
I am learning scala , that is why I am asking this kind of questions
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`println` is a side effect: you won't be able to reason about the output of `compareToHello`.

Recall

```
scala> def f: Unit = println("Hello")
f: Unit

scala> f
Hello

scala> f == "Hello"
<console>:9: warning: comparing values of types Unit and String using `==' will always yield false
              f == "Hello"
                ^
Hello
res7: Boolean = false

scala> f == ()
<console>:9: warning: comparing values of types Unit and Unit using `==' will always yield true
              f == ()
                ^
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
Hello
res8: Boolean = true
```

What you can do is to make this function pure, by returning a string instead:

```
def compareToHello (a:String) = a match {
  case "Hello" => "Hello"
  case _ => "error"
}
```

and assert as follows:

```
assert(test == "Hello")
```